# Building a comma-separated string of related values to display in a ListView control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new to vb and currently I have this project on hand which requires me to display some employee information. I've stored all my data in ms access, in a table called "ScheduleInfo". There are three rows: "WorkerID", "TaskNo", and "TimeTaken". Each worker will need a certain amount of time to complete each task.

The problem is I have to display in vb.net the task (grouped together), numbers of worker who are able to do the task (count the workers according from task), and which are the workers (WorkerID).

I only managed to display first two column on a `ListView`, which group my tasks together and count how many workers are available for the task.

**WorkerID | TaskNo | TimeTaken**

- 1     |    1   |    7.5
- 4     |    1   |    2.5
- 1     |    2   |    3.5
- 2     |    2   |    1.5
- 1     |    3   |    2.5
- 2     |    3   |    4.5
- 3     |    3   |    3.5
- 2     |    4   |    3.5
  *-and the list goes on-*

i couldn't attach an image of how my database looks like, here is roughly an idea.

i'm trying to display it on vb like:

**TaskNo | No. of Workers | Workers available**

- 1 | 2 | 1 , 4
- 2 | 2 | 1 , 2
- 3 | 3 | 1 , 2 , 3

-and the list goes on according to how many task i have-

**my code**

> ```
>  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>         conn.ConnectionString = myConString
>         conn.Open()
>
>         Dim SQLString As String = ("SELECT [TaskNo], COUNT(*) FROM ScheduleInfo GROUP BY TaskNo")
>         cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQLString, conn)
>
>
>         da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
>         ds = New DataSet
>         da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "ScheduleInfo")
>         da.Fill(ds, "ScheduleInfo")
>         dt = ds.Tables("ScheduleInfo")
>
>
>         LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("TaskNo", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
>         LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("No of Workers", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
>         LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("List Of Workers", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
>
>         For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows()
>             Dim lst As ListViewItem
>             lst = LstViewScheduleInfo.Items.Add(row(0))
>
>             For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
>                 lst.SubItems.Add(row(i))
>             Next
>
>         Next
>
>         conn.Close()
>
>     End Sub
> ```

i am not sure if this is the proper way of doing, this is what i have.
Right now I have no idea how I could loop through the database and pull out the workers who are available for the job. Do I use another sql query?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: the LV shown just seems to show summary type info.  you will need a different dataset for the detail.  The "List Of Workers" column seems odd.

Comment: how do you know that which workers are available for this task from your database? if you can show some data from your database that will be help full to understand.

Comment: what you are showing all deals with HOW MANY type things - how many tasks, how many workers busy and how many workers free.  For WHICH workers are free you need a different query.  We cant help without more info about the data as per @Ikiet 's comment

Comment: That is a Table, not a database. Presumably there is a Worker table and presumably `ScheduleInfo` only has an entry for a worker if they are busy; and it is removed/cleared or has a status change when they are done.  So create a query on `Worker` to select all of them who DO NOT have an 'open' entry in `ScheduleInfo`.  Access has query building tools to help with this, then you can either call that query or paste the SQL into your app.

Comment: @Plutonix lets say only one worker can do one task, so i have randomize one worker in later part of the assignment. but right now i have to get my "list of worker" to display. like example for row 1 in my listview, it will be TaskNo 1, second column will be 2 as there's only 2 Task, 3rd column will be like "1,4" meaning only worker 1 and worker 4 are available. i know i've to loop it, but where do i put the loop? do i use one more dataset like you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of your question is "How do I build a string of [WorkerID] values for the [TaskNo] in each row of my DataTable?

This is a very common question, and the method depends on the database we are using. For example, MySQL offers a `GROUP_CONCAT()` function that enables us to do it as part of the main query. For Access database applications, a common solution is to use a custom VBA function like [this one](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to string together the related values.

Unfortunately, user-defined VBA functions can only be used in queries that are run from within the Microsoft Access application itself, so we cannot use that approach from within a .NET application. Therefore, the .NET application has to build its own list of values.

The following code illustrates one way of doing that. (It's C# code, but the VB.NET code would be very similar.)

```csharp
using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    con.Open();

    var dt = new System.Data.DataTable("ListInfo");
    using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
    {
        // fill the DataTable with three columns, the third column being
        //     a placeholder that we will fill in below
        string sql =
                "SELECT [TaskNo], COUNT(*) AS NumWorkers, '' AS WorkersAvailable " +
                "FROM ScheduleInfo GROUP BY [TaskNo]";
        da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
        da.Fill(dt);

        using (var cmd2 = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            // create a Prepared Statement that we will use for each iteration
            cmd2.Connection = con;
            cmd2.CommandText =
                    "SELECT [WorkerID] FROM ScheduleInfo " +
                    "WHERE [TaskNo] = ? " +
                    "ORDER BY [WorkerID]";
            cmd2.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer);
            cmd2.Prepare();

            // foreach row of the DataTable, build the string of WorkerID values
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                cmd2.Parameters[0].Value = dr["TaskNo"];
                string workerList = "";
                using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        workerList += ", " + rdr["WorkerID"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                dr["WorkersAvailable"] = workerList.Substring(2);  // remove leading ", "
            }
        }

        // for demo purposes, just dump the DataTable to the console
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6}  {1,10}  {2,16}", "TaskNo", "NumWorkers", "WorkersAvailable"));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6}  {1,10}  {2,16}", "------", "----------", "----------------"));
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,6}  {1,10}  {2,-16}", dr["TaskNo"], dr["NumWorkers"], dr["WorkersAvailable"]));
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

For sample data in [ScheduleInfo]

```
WorkerID  TaskNo  TimeTaken
--------  ------  ---------
       1       1        7.5
       4       1        2.5
       1       2        3.5
       2       2        1.5
       1       3        2.5
       2       3        4.5
       3       3        3.5
       2       4        3.5
```

the console output is

```
TaskNo  NumWorkers  WorkersAvailable
------  ----------  ----------------
     1           2  1, 4
     2           2  1, 2
     3           3  1, 2, 3
     4           1  2
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. i'll try my best to understand it. at least now i have an idea of how my codes will look like. btw, one thing i forgot to add on. after i display the record. i have to randomize a worker from each task and add the time together. do i need another query to pull out my time and store in array form?

Comment: @Crayon That sounds like a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: by right the whole thing is to generate out a sequence of employee. what i dun get it how to pull out the time if both of my commandtext doesn't pull out the time

Comment: @Crayon While you are looping through the rows in the DataTable you could always pull both the [WorkerID] *and* the [TimeTaken], and add one value for each [TaskNo] to your total time.

Comment: thank you soooooooooo much, i managed to get it to work. THANKS!

Comment: @Crayon You're welcome. Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer to indicate that your problem has been resolved. (It will also make it more likely that others will help you in the future.)